# OpenMP: What is the benefit of nesting parallelizations?

Tags: c++, multithreading, nested, parallel-processing, openmp

From what I understand, `#pragma omp parallel` and its variations basically execute the following block in a number of concurrent threads, which corresponds to the number of CPUs. When having nested parallelizations - parallel for within parallel for, parallel function within parallel function etc. - what happens on the inner parallelization?

I'm new to OpenMP, and the case I have in mind is probably rather trivial - multiplying a vector with a matrix. This is done in two nested for loops. Assuming the number of CPUs is smaller than the number of elements in the vector, is there any benefit in trying to run the inner loop in parallel? Will the total number of threads be larger than the number of CPUs, or will the inner loop be executed sequentially?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(1) Nested parallelism in OpenMP:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5270/aewbc/index.html

You need to turn on nested parallelism by setting `OMP_NESTED` or `omp_set_nested` because many implementations turn off this feature by default, even some implementations didn't support nested parallelism fully. If turned on, whenever you meet `parallel for`, OpenMP will create the number of threads as defined in `OMP_NUM_THREADS`. So, if 2-level parallelism, the total number of threads would be N^2, where N = `OMP_NUM_THREADS`.

Such nested parallelism will cause oversubscription, (i.e., the number of busy threads is greater than the cores), which may degrade the speedup. In an extreme case, where nested parallelism is called recursively, threads could be bloated (e.g., creating 1000s threads), and computer just wastes time for context switching. In such case, you may control the number of threads dynamically by setting `omp_set_dynamic`.

(2) An example of matrix-vector multiplication: the code would look like:

```
// Input:  A(N by M), B(M by 1)
// Output: C(N by 1)
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
  for (int j = 0; j < M; ++j)
     C[i] += A[i][j] * B[j];
```

In general, parallelizing inner loops while outer loops are possible is bad because of forking/joining overhead of threads. (though many OpenMP implementations pre-create threads, it still requires some to dispatch tasks to threads and to call implicit barrier at the end of parallel-for)

Your concern is the case of where N < # of CPU. Yes, right, in this case, the speedup would be limited by N, and letting nested parallelism will definitely have benefits.

However, then the code would cause oversubscription if N is sufficiently large. I'm just thinking the following solutions:

- Changing the loop structure so that only 1-level loop exists. (It looks doable)
- Specializing the code: if N is small, then do nested parallelism, otherwise don't do that.
- Nested parallelism with `omp_set_dynamic`. But, please make it sure how `omp_set_dynamic` controls the number of threads and the activity of threads. Implementations may vary.

Comment: The way to deal with small N without putting the parallelism one level down is just to use collapse; `#pragma omp parallel for collapse`; `for (int i=0; i<N; ++i)`, etc.   That notionally merges the i and j loops.    As to the other issue, "However, then the code would cause oversubscription if N is sufficiently large." -- no it wouldn't.  If you're putting the parallel for after the i, the main thread will do the i loop, and every i iteration you'll do a fork, divide up the j-work, and join.   (Although as you say, most OpenMP implementations will use a common thread pool now.)

Comment: Maybe some confusion. I'm talking nested parallelism: Having nested parallel loop will mostly cause oversubscription. If N is equal or larger than the number of cores (say n), then n threads will be created at the outer for-i loop. Then, each thread will fork another n threads when the thread meets the for-j loop. So, n*n threads are working on n cores. You can easily check it by using system utilities.

Comment: Ok, fair enough, and that is what he asked.   But of course one wouldn't do that; that's exactly what collapse is for -- parallelize over both loops without incurring the overhead.

Answer (score 9):

For something like dense linear algebra, where all the potential parallelism is already lain bare in one place in nice wide for loops, you don't need nested parallism -- if you do want to protect against the case of having (say) really narrow matricies where the leading dimension might be smaller than the number of cores, then all you need is the [collapse](http://wikis.sun.com/display/openmp/Loop+Collapse) directive which notionally flattens the multiple loops into one.

Nested parallelism is for those cases where the parallelism isn't all exposed at once -- say you want to do 2 simultaneous function evaluations, each of which could usefully utilize 4 cores, and you have an 8 core system.  You call the function in a parallel section, and within the function definition there is an additional, say, parallel for.

Comment: The vector*matrix is a concrete example for a general problem: does OpenMP bother to create more threads when the number of threads it has created in an outer block already cover all cores? If so, wouldn't it add some scheduling overhead? And if not, is there any reason whatsoever to create nested parallel blocks?

Comment: OpenMP will create as many threads as you ask it to with environment variables (`OMP_NUM_THREADS`) or with options to pragmas `#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)` or with function calls `omp_set_num_threads()`.  The default is generally the number of cores the runtime sees available, and that's normally the number of threads you'd want doing real work.   With matrix-vector multiplication, the omp parallel for is all you need -- with the default static scheduling of the loop, it'll break it up into OMP_NUM_THREADS threads (which, by default, is the number of cores) and alls well.

Comment: Nested parallelism is for situations where the amount of parallelism available at the top level of what you're doing is much less than the number of cores, and you want to make use of parallelism at lower levels to make sure all your cores are doing real work.   eg, the example above of only having two function calls -- or general sections of code -- in the main body of code which could be done concurrently, but within each function call or code section is more parallelism that could be exploited.

Comment: Answering this more directly "does OpenMP bother to create more threads when the number of threads it has created in an outer block already cover all cores?" -- yes.  OpenMP creates as many threads each time as you tell it to; the default is no nested and to use OMP_NUM_THREADS threads; and if you don't tell it what that is, that'll be the number of cores on your system.  If you allow nested, the default is to create OMP_NUM_THREADS threads at each level, which will oversubscribe.   But you can control that, with environment variables, directives on the pragma line, or functions.

Answer (score 3):

At the outer level use the NUM_THREADS(num_groups) clause to set the number of threads to use. If your outer loop has a count N, and the number of processors or cores is num_cores, use num_groups = min(N,num_cores). At the inner level, you need to set the number of sub-threads for each thread group so that the total number of subthreads equals the number of cores. So if num_cores = 8, N = 4, then num_groups = 4. At the lower level each sub-thread should use 2 threads (since 2+2+2+2 = 8) so use the NUM_THREADS(2) clause. You can collect the number of sub-threads into an array with one element per outer region thread (with num_groups elements).

This strategy always makes optimal use of your cores. When N < num_cores some nested parallelisation occurs. When N >= num_cores the array of subthread counts contains all 1s and so the inner loop is effectively serial.