# OpenMP run threads but continue main

Tags: c, openmp

I am trying to use OpenMP for threading as it is cross platform.  However I can't work out how to make the code after the parallel continue while the loop is running? It basically just executes the first loop in parallel but never gets to the second non parallel loop?

```
int main() {
    #pragma omp parallel 
        while(1) {
            Sleep(4000);
            printf("doing work in thread %d, nthreads %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads());
        }


    while (1) {
        Sleep(4000);
        printf("Hello from main %d, nthreads %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads());
    }
}
```

Comment: You cant to have worker thread running after end of "omp parallel" region (in your example the parallel region is first 'while(){ ...}'. There is an invisible barrier at the end of parallel region (just before second while).

Comment: Actually, OpenMP alone is a bad choice for what you want. It's not "another threading lib"; it's a different solution with its own rules to follow. A better solution would be to start a separate thread (which could use OpenMP), and let the main thread proceed to the "non-parallel" loop. A more detailed answer is possible if you describe the use case in more details.

Comment: @AlexeyKukanov, I agree but OpenMP have the benefits described in the question.

Comment: @JohanLundberg: sure; but there are other cross-platform threading libraries that could complement OpenMP. Moreover, the new language standard (C11) adds threads, so sooner rather than later one would not even need such a library, at least for most widely used platforms - while OpenMP will keep its other values over "typical" threading libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could just make one of the threads your special thread within your omp parallel block

```
int main() {
    #pragma omp parallel 
        if(omp_get_thread_num()==0){
             while(1) {
                Sleep(4000);
               printf("Hello from main %d, nthreads %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads());
             }
        }else{
             while(1) {
                Sleep(4000);
                printf("doing work in thread %d, nthreads %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads());
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Weather this makes sense in your case is hard to judge without more details.

You could also use `sections`. Example from here: http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/#Sections :

```
#pragma omp parallel // starts a new team
{
   //Work0(); // this function would be run by all threads.

   #pragma omp sections // divides the team into sections
   { 
     // everything herein is run only once.
     { Work1(); }
     #pragma omp section
     { Work2();
       Work3(); }
     #pragma omp section
     { Work4(); }
   }

   //Work5(); // this function would be run by all threads.
}
```

You can do nested renationalisation: [OpenMP: What is the benefit of nesting parallelizations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317551/openmp-what-is-the-benefit-of-nesting-parallelizations)

Comment: Thanks Johan, What I want to achieve is run one thread that will loop forever, but the rest of the main code should continue. So I only want the main thread and this other one thread to be parallel and they will do different things. This is faily normal on other threading libs. The program runs (thread 0) then it spawns a thread to do stuff and the code continues.

Comment: I realize this. Try using sections.