# Run thread in background and continue main with OpenMP

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

Here is an example of what I want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

void increment1(){
  int x;
  x=0;
  for(int i = 0; i<30000000000000;i++){
    ++x;
  }
  printf("%d\n",x );
}

int main(){
  #pragma omp parallel  
  {
    #pragma omp sections  
    {
      #pragma omp section
      { increment1(); }
    }
  }
  printf("Continue\n" );

  return 0;
}
```

As you can see `increment1()` takes too much time to finish. My question is how can i set this task in background and print first `printf("Continue\n" );`message and then `printf("%d\n",x );` once `increment1()` is finished.
Also tried [OpenMP run threads but continue main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131875/openmp-run-threads-but-continue-main) but it does not work

Comment: Note that *"it does not work"* is never a sufficient problem description.

Comment: "As you can see" No, where should we see this?  A clever compiler might optimize the function quite a bit to make it take only very little time.

Comment: Infinite numbers do not exist. The value you use will not fit in an `int`, so you end up overflowing it. What happens from there is undefined behavior, anything can happen, including a program crash or the program seemingly working ok. Speculations about what your program does are useless until this bug is fixed. As a side note, you should not go anywhere near OpenMP or multi-threading if you don't even know the limits of the standard integer types. Start by learning the basics of C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenMP doesn't work like this. Idiomatically you use OpenMP to make the loop in `increment1` run faster, e.g. by applying `#pragma omp parallel for`. Of course the specific worksharing approach depends on what your *actual* function does.

If you do need to use functional parallelism, i.e. run different functions at the same time, **all** of the functions that are supposed to run simultaneously (therefore including the code doing the `printf`) need to be in `section`s (or `task`s).

Comment: forget the increment example. Assume that function increment1() takes too long and we cant do anything for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use omp tasks:

```
int main() {
#pragma omp parallel
  {
#pragma omp single
    {
#pragma omp task
      increment1(300000000);
#pragma omp task // if you leave out this pragma the printf will be executed 
                 // by the same thread that created the increment1 task
                 // otherwise it can be scheduled by any OMP thread
      printf("continue\n");

#pragma omp taskwait
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This example will create two tasks (one for the `increment1` function and one for `printf("continue\n")` which will be distributed among the OMP threads. The tasks might be scheduled in any order, but when there are more OMP threads than tasks they will be scheduled concurrently.

Additional note: The `#pragma omp single` directive is there so that the tasks are only created by one thread. other wise each thread would create a task for `increment1` and the `printf` statement.