# Multiple threads per task OpenMP

Tags: c, task, openmp

Is it possible to assign more than one thread to a task in OpenMP (4.x)?

General outline of the problem I am trying to solve:

```
#pragma omp task
{
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2)
    <for loop>
}
```

Comment: OpenMP creates a worker every time you call it. Beside doing the for loop, I don´t think you can spawn a custom thread with it. Maybe try to launch a std::thread to do what you want

Comment: @Bl4ckb0ne this is highly inaccurate. Also you should not mix `std::thread` and OpenMP.

Comment: @Zulan that´s true, I never tought about that, but it makes sense. I think I misunderstood the question of OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with nested parallel regions, exactly with the syntax you describe. You need to specifically enable it via setting the environment variable `OMP_NESTED=True` or calling `omp_set_nested` and it needs to be supported by the implementation.

That said, you have to be very careful in terms of performance. Normally OpenMP will uses 1 thread per core, which is very nice for scheduler and hardware. Nested parallel regions will cause oversubscription (more than one thread per core) thus can cause performance issues when threads are competing for cores. This is particularly true, because many tasks could potentially open up man parallel regions.

Also take a look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4320422/620382) about nested parallel regions on nested loops.

Comment: Just a clarification on the repercussions of what you describe. If I run the code on a 16 core machine, and use the `num_threads(2)` clause on the for loop does this not mean 8 concurrent tasks will run with 2 threads each? Or will it launch 16 tasks with 2 threads each hence the over-subscription?

Comment: EDIT (new comment as 5 mins was exceeded): Ignore this I have just reread the discussion you posted. 16^2 threads will be available.

Comment: 16 * 2, you could of course limit the outer parallel region to 8 to avoid oversubscription, but then you might get load balance issues.

Comment: MSDN seems to think its to the power of the depth not a multiplication https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk3zt8e1.aspx

Comment: @BenHazelwood It would be 16^2 if you didn't explicitly use `num_threads(2)`.