# Parallelizing two for loops with OpenMP in C++ does not give better performance

Tags: c++, loops, parallel-processing, nested, openmp

I have an issue with parallelizing two for loops with OpenMP in C++. I have a memberfunction CallFunction(i,j) which sets for every i and j independent member variables to a specific value and returns a weighted sum of this values. Because these functions are independent for different combinations of i and j, I want to parallelize this process. I tried it in the following way:

```
double optimal_value = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:optimal_value)
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{       
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if(i == j) continue;
        optimal_value += CallFunction(i,j);
    }
}
```

Above code does not have a significant effect on my runtime. I achieve almost the same runtime with and without "#pragma omp parallel for". Would it be better to write the nested loop as one loop and parallelize it? I have to idea how to make it work. Do I need further commands or settings except for activated openmp?

My system is running with a dual core cpu.

Would you please help me how I have to do it right?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What does your CallFunction do?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] - including specific example for `n`. Also include your time measurement method and specific time measurement results as well as specific hardware description of CPU and memory.

Comment: Which part of your example do you consider expensive CPU wise? Is it the CallFunction ? The result of the function goes to optimal_value, which is shared between all calls. Due to the sharing, optimal_value might be protected with a guard, that might also influence CallFunction. Maybe you could look into the machine code generated?

Comment: My class has multipe 2-dimensional vectors and CallFunction changes values which exclusively depend on i and j, I think there is no conflict. The only thing at which threads could conflict is reading a member variable, but this variable does not change, so this must be okay? Unfortunately, CallFunction is too complex to give a simple example. n is 25 in this case.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark "should" not "could" ;)

Comment: @Jesper Madsen CallFunction is independently executed many times and therefore can be parallelized. Unfortunately, I am a rookie in programming and cant handle any machine code. I am trying to implement an optimization algorithm from a paper for my masters thesis and in the paper parallel computing of the method is recommended.

Comment: @do-math did you make sure that CPU load matches multithreading execution? Is CPU really ~100% loaded?

Comment: @k.v I use Visual Studio and can see there how much CPU is used. When I execute above code within another loop  I see several peaks to 100% CPU Power. I think that these peaks correspond to the code above. I have 4GB RAM if this is important.

Comment: @do-math and how much time does the code you are parallelising take? If it's relatively small amount of time it may appear that cost of parallelising is comparable to actual work cost.

Comment: @do-math and do you compile and run Release configuration?

Comment: @k.v Above Code takes about 1 second. But I have to execute it a few thousand times.  I dont understand the second question. I compile and run in Visual Studio.

Comment: @do-math regarding build configurations: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx0123s5.aspx

Comment: @do-math parallelization has some overheads. If parallel code is invoked for 1000 times that means you are paying 1000 times of this overhead. Maybe there is a possibility to move parallelization to higher level?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I did not understand by your comment that that's not how OpenMP works ...  Secondly ... do-math ... As suggested above your "n" has a big say in how much speedup you can achieve. If I were you I would try two things try a very large value of n ... Secondly ... Splitting the computation into two ... That is ... Parallelizing the inner for loop too ... So then you will have another optValue inside the first loop where the second loop adds to. This will also help the speedup.

Comment: @High Performance Mark n ist not adjustable to arbitrary values. I want to speed up my code für n==25. I have given the theoretical algorithm from a science paper and implemented it by myself, but my implementation is 10 times slower and therefore I am worried about it. I thought that the reason might be the parallelization thing as my parallelization gives no performance improvement.

Comment: @AdityaG Could you please give me more detailed instructions? I think i got your idea, but I am not sure how to implement it. Thanks everybody for your help!

Comment: @k.v. I am running my program in Debug mode. I tried to activate release mode, but it does not work yet, because some external includes are not found then. Are there huge performance gaps between those modes?

Comment: @do-math yes there are. To name a few - compiler optimization options and debug-only checks in STL containters. Possibly, OpenMP behavior can also differ. There is a possibility of significant performance increase after moving to release configuration. I strongly suggest to put an effort to bringing Release configuration to life if computation time as a significant factor to you

Comment: @k.v. I did it now, but the difference is not significant. Last thing I could think of is hardware issues. How much performance difference is possible between a 5 years old CPU and a new one?

Comment: You can trivially exploit the parallelism in the two loops by using "collapse(2)", though whether it will improve performance is unclear. Doing so will introduce a divrem operation that adds cost; so it will depend on how things are aligned in the caches, load-imbalance and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the parallelization of two loops

```
        double optimal_value = 0;
        double begin = omp_get_wtime();
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:optimal_value)
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            num_tr = omp_get_num_threads();
            double optimal_value_in = 0.0;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:optimal_value_in)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                if((i == j)) continue;
                optimal_value_in += CallFunction(i,j);
            }
            optimal_value += optimal_value_in;

        }
        double end = omp_get_wtime();
        double elapsed_secs = double(end - begin);
        cout<<"#############  "<<"Using #Threads "<<num_tr<<endl;
        cout<<"#############  "<<optimal_value<<" Time For Parallel Execution :: "<<elapsed_secs<<endl;
```

The thing here is (also mentioned above in comments by others) ... I am not sure if you will see some speedup with just `n=25`  with the body of CallFunction as

```
double CallFunction(int i, int j){
    return i*j;
}
```

with `n=250000` and with 8 threads, I got a speed up of `4.43` so it will strongly depend on what is done in CallFunction.

Comment: **Do not** nest multiple `#pragma omp parallel` unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: @Zulan can you explain what is wrong with the implementation above? Yes nested parallel regions are bad .. I will be helpful if you can explain what is explain more ??!!

Comment: There is some discussion about the issues with nested parallelism [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4317551) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47662767). The correct solution is to use `collapse`. Unfortunately I cannot provide a full answer to this question, because it is underspecified. This is another issue with your answer - it involves a lot of guessing about the question.