# Is there a difference between nested parallelism and collapsed for loops?

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

I know that enabling nested parallelism will allow for a nested omp parallel for loop to also be parallelized.  But I use collapse(2) in my nested for loops (for inside of for) instead.

Is there a difference?  Why or why not?  Assume the best case scenario: no dependence between the loop indices and other things equal.

Comment: *"...a software engineer at Microsoft working on Skype for Business.."*? How about sketching an MCVE-example-code and posting what have you tried so far? This is the StackOverflow culture of asking questions, that may attract Community Members to come and help. You might want to update your post and present some already elaborated experiments and bechmarks collected, that illustrate your interest already spent on trying to analyse and further investigate the MCVE and its possible solutions

Comment: I'm not stuck on a problem and need help with my code.  I was simply posing a question about the differences of how OpenMP implements nested parallelism for the purpose of my own understanding as I'm taking a course and we're using OpenMP.  My professor mentioned using omp_set_nested, which I did not do because I understood that it would probably cause a ballooning of threads which would impact performance.   A for-inside-a-for without loop index dependency is a pretty straightforward explanation, in fact it can't get much more minimal than that.

Comment: By ballooning, I meant schedule contention.  If one iteration encounters another parallel section and starts another several threads then the next iteration that does so will also try to.  From my reading, I understood that collapsing the loop would be more performant.  However my professor mentioned that we should use omp_set_nested for the assignment, so I was concerned whether or not there was an actual difference.

Comment: The cleanest step is to setup an independent thread-count monitor and document the evolution of the number of process-spawned child-threads, isn't it? Loop-unrolling being another, technically implemented countermeasure ( where code analysis permit doing so in compiler / optimisation phases ). So collecting records of evidence may be quite interesting. If your professor is not leading your work into quantitatively supported benchmarking, it is the best time to change the professor. Easy typed syntax-sugar #pragma omp * decorated code has to be understood v/s **[tag:parallelism-Amdahl]** costs.

Comment: If it were not for the StackOverflow censorship, the [tag:parallelism-Amdahl] would have the full chapter on setup-costs discussed. >>> https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3 ( still not sure, why Mr. Martijn Pieters has deleted the majority of the explanatory text, c'est la vie ). Anyway, the costs of going parallel are the main concern ( blocking is obviously a sign of a poor or agnostic resource-mapping ). So the thorough benchmarking strategy concentrates on each phase of going omp parallel & on the actual [TIME]-domain costs of respective constructors. Cost-aware Amdahl Law rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a huge difference - use `collapse` (not `collapsed`). Do not use nested parallelism.

Nested parallelism means that there are independent teams of threads working on the different levels of worksharing. You can run into all sorts of trouble either with oversubscribing CPU cores to too many threads - or not utilizing CPU cores because some threads are in the wrong team which has no work right now. It's rather hard to get decent performance out of nested parallelism. This is why you usually need to explicitly enable it.

Collapsing loops on the other hand means that the different loops are joint on a work-sharing level. This allows one team of threads (usually with as many threads as available CPU cores) to efficiently work the different iterations of the loops.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  That's actually a typo, I meant omp collapse.  I did so because I understood the overhead of nested parallelism and how some chunks pointed to by the outer loop may not be scheduled due to waiting on other chunks to finish from the inner loop.  However, I was working on a homework assignment where my professor mentioned that we should be using omp_set_nested.  I became worried that not using collapse(2) would have impacted my performance negatively and wanted a better grasp.

Comment: Well, good luck with your professor :-). Ideally you would implement both and back up your theoretical knowledge with actual measurements to show how one is better than the other.